# Spring cloud config with consul

Tags: spring-boot, config, spring-cloud, consul, spring-cloud-config

I'm having an issue with finding documentation/ a way to hook up spring-cloud-config-server with consul. What I want is spring cloud config server to serve the keys/values from consul. The idea is to be able to have one interface that can serve the application properties or config files. That way we can choose to use git, consul without impacting client apps if the data store changes for the properties. Is this possible? Ideally we would also be able to use ZooKeeper, Netflix's Archauis etc. I can update with more details once I'm in front of my computer.

I did have the test application working with Git, but since wiring up with consul it seems to require the Git uri still.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use spring-cloud-config with consul without any issue..It's pretty straight forward..You can share the code sample and let us know the challenge so that we can help...

Comment: Currently not possible to have config server serve configuration via consul. Clients can use consul directly, but not via config server.

Comment: Thanks @spencergibb that is what I suspected. So am I correct in concluding only git, file systems and vault can be used when using spring config server. If we want to use ZooKeeper, archauis or consul we have to use those projects in our client applications. I assume we could build our own implementations of those for spring cloud server and contribute back into the project.

Comment: yes, that is correct.